# Preventing Android Browsers from Exiting Full Screen on Plyr Double Tap

Tags: javascript

I'm unable to prevent Android browsers to exit full screen on double tap, on Plyr.

I want the player not to exit full screen mode wen double tap, as I will add double tap to skip 10sec of video.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Plyr Video Player</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.plyr.io/3.6.2/plyr.css">
</head>
<body>
  <video id="player" controls>
    <source src="mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>

  <script src="https://cdn.plyr.io/3.6.2/plyr.js"></script>
  <script>
    var player = new Plyr('#player');
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```